Xorg Driver choice for Gen 3 Intel GPU HD4000 i5-3320M
My laptop has HD4000 Intel GPU (i5-3320M).
What GPU driver is most compatible for recent versions of Xorg/Linux? (for non-3D applications, such as Xorg)
One page recommend crocus for anything up to Haswell, is this correct for laptop version of HD4000?
What are all Xorg GPU drivers compatible with HD4000?
How to determine what driver Xorg uses?
I checked X.org.log, but there's a lot of info, not sure which line is relevant.
lspci |grep "3rd Gen" |grep Graphi
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
This question is more about Xorg drivers, I know kernel GPU driver is a different thing.
Yes, there's a number of pages on inet, but often at the very end it usually says that everything above is outdated.
Thank you.

I use fbdev and modeset X11 drivers, and the i915 kernel driver. Acceleration is handled through DRI.

Thanks. Whats "DRI"? Do you mean 2D or 3D acceleration?
I've seen online that fbdev means ancient frame buffer driver and is "very slow". What you think?

Does "modeset" have any meaning? Or whats its relation to MESA?

If there is no dedicated GPU RAM, the framebuffer will be in system RAM, that's what fbdev does. Rendering to the framebuffer with the CPU is slow, but we don't have to: we have a GPU that can access system RAM, and that has per-application command queues, so we can use the Direct Rendering Infrastructure (DRI) to update the framebuffer. The modeset driver also allows changing the graphics mode for fbdev, that's the last bit that was missing for a complete driver.

The intel Xorg driver has been considered deprecated for years now but it may actually work better for you because for instance it support the TearFree option.
Then there's a built-in modeset driver, that just works and requires no drivers whatsoever.
I've never heard of crocus TBO, nor it's present in Fedora 40.
As for the driver that's in use, run sudo grep -i driver /var/log/Xorg.0.log.
Use what works for you.

Thank you!Your grep gives quite a bit of output,which I'm not sure how to interpret, have to split:
[    26.838] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[    26.838] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[    26.838] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[    26.838] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    26.838] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    26.839]  Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.839]  ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2

[    26.841] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    26.841] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    26.841] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    26.874]  ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[    27.741] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: crocus
[    27.741] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    28.086]  Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    28.086]  ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.4

There's more output for grep, but the rest doesn't seem relevant for my question.
This line is especially confusing:
modeset(0): [DRI2] DRI driver: crocus.
Is it modeset or crocus driver?

"I've never heard of crocus TBO" - This is from ?wiki?.alpinelinux.org:  "For all Intel Graphics up to Haswell, the user must manually select crocus Mesa driver in order to let the graphics work properly". Sorry didn't save the link.

You're seemingly automatically using the modeset driver: Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so 

Crocus is a MESA/DRI driver, it's loaded automatically for 3D acceleration, you don't need to specify it anywhere.

Thank you, but can you determine from above the above logs which 2D driver Xorg uses? It mentions fbdev, modeset, VESA etc.

Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so - you're using the built-in modesetting driver. Also check this https://askubuntu.com/a/23240
